# Quickly create a wrappers for classes to count undisposed instances?

Tags: c#, .net, testing

Is there any tool or library that will let me easily wrap a class, say `DbDataReader` with another class called, say `WDbDataReader`, for debugging purposes?

My particular problem is that I think my code is not properly calling `DbDataReader`'s `Dispose`. I first though about subclassing `DbDataReader` and having a `static int` that counts created instances that have not been disposed. The problem is that I don't create the instance from my code but by calling `OleDbCommand`'s `ExecuteReader` method.

So now I want to create a class that would look something like this:

```
public class WDbDataReader
{
    private static int _Counter = 0;
    private DbDataReader _Source;

    public WDbDataReader(DbDataReader source)
    {
        _Source = source;
        _Counter++;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _Counter--;
        _Source.Dispose();
    }

    // implement all used DbDataReader methods here
}
```

And then surround all calls to `OleDbCommand`'s `ExecuteReader` method with a `new WDbDataReader(...)`. So I was wondering if there is a quicker or automated way to do this because I might need to do it for several other classes in the future.

I'm not sure but I believe I could use Pex or Moles for this purpose. But I've been checking their tutorials and I believe that's way more advanced that what I need right now.

Comment: Are you trying to test or debug?

Comment: Debug actually. My bad. Edited...

Comment: If you're worried about disposing DbDataReader why not wrap it in a `using` block? That will ensure that the DbDataReader is disposed.

Comment: Can't. I need to keep a reference to the reader for later use on some cases.

Comment: How long are you holding onto the reader references for? In general you don't want to leave those connections open for too long.

Comment: For as long as my application's user wants to.

Comment: @jsoldi, that seems like a bad design. Why does the use have a control of the lifetime of the `DbDataReader`? Can't you read it completely and the open new read if user requests more items, or something like that?

Comment: @jsoldi: @svick is right, is there any reason you can't load everything into objects and then dispose of the reader or just return a DataSet?

Comment: Yea. I´ll do that. But still I think my question is more general than whether a `DbDataReader` should stay open or not, and if someone in my code is not disposing it this my be a sign of another problem. So my question holds.